# How to Override standard close (X) button in a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I go about changing what happens when a user clicks the close (red X) button in a Windows Forms application (in C#)? I want to add a simple DialogResult and Messagebox to ask user if he's sure about closing the form.

Comment: But have a look into the [FormClosing Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: @Fildor Up-right corner, the default close button.

Comment: @Fildor, yeah it is, what are you talking about?

Comment: Ok, nevermind. Looked at the wrong components. It's been too long without "Vanilla" for me haha...

Comment: @Fildor I don't understand what you mean, but Julius already answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle the FormClosing event on the Form class. In the handler, you are able to set the value of the CancelEventArgs.Cancel property to **true** to prevent closure of the form.

Example:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Close?", "Close", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

You can create the handler method by double-clicking the event in the Properties tab while the Windows Forms designer is open:

[image: FormClosing Event in Properties Tab]

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing?view=windowsdesktop-6.0